# Firebase Ionic code implementation

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm really stuck with this code and can't find the solution. I have created an Ionic app with connection to Firebase and my auth is working fine; can pass the data, but I can't see how should I pass the following code correctly. Form Structure:

[image: Form Structure]

My code for passing data, the Service:

```
factory('Products', function($firebaseArray) {
  var productsRef = new Firebase("https://kidsmoments-19623.firebaseio.com/momentos");
    var products =$firebaseArray(productsRef.child('products'));
     var Products = {
         saveProduct: function (product, image) {
                 var newProduct = {
                     name: product.name
                     , tagline: product.tagline
                     , description: product.description
                     , price: product.price
                     , image: image
                 };
                 return products.add(newProduct).then(function () {  console.log('added');
            })
    }
        };
return Products;

         }
)
```

Comment: Sorry the error that I get is: VM23799 ionic.bundle.js:26771 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ProductsProvider <- Products <- settingsController

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to add 'Products' as a dependency in the controller you were working on.

Also you should try Firebase three-way-binding:

```
.factory("Products", ["$firebaseObject", "$rootScope",
    function($firebaseObject, $rootScope) {
        return function() {

            // create a reference to the database where our Products is.
            var ref = ($rootScope.ref.child("Products"))

            return $firebaseObject(reg);
        }
    }
])
```

And from the controller:

```
Products().$bindTo($scope, "products");
```

Now any change that you do to $scope.products will be synced to Firebase

Comment: Well I have in my controller Products: the last one I added...<br>'Use Strict';
angular.module('App').controller('settingsController', function ($scope, $state,$cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $log, $location,$http,$ionicPopup, $firebaseObject, Auth, FURL, Products) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref

Comment: Please write code with the proper indentation, It's easier to read that way. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Ok , I think is has to be with the firebase configuration. In one hand I have the   firebase.initializeApp(FURL);  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  var auth = $firebaseAuth(); and in other hand I need to create de product.js with the firebase configuation: var productsRef = new Firebase("https://kidsmoments-19623.firebaseio.com/momentos");
    var products =$firebaseArray(productsRef.child('products'));, sorry I dont know how to break lines. Thanks

Comment: Use four spaces to make code indentation, I can't understand your comment..Please try to be more clear.

Comment: Hi Yossi, I am really messed up. Could you plese take a look at the code here?     https://github.com/cookyourweb/firebase-ionic-auth-data.git     Thanks for your time

Comment: Lets try to make this usable for other pepole as well, Upload your code here: https://gist.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an entity products, so make a reference to that entity and push your data like this:

```
var productsRef = new Firebase("https://kidsmoments-19623.firebaseio.com/momentos/products");

productsRef.push({
  name: product.name,
  tagline: product.tagline,
  description: product.description,
  price: product.price,
  image: image
})
```

**Update** About the error that you get please make sure you have injected the provider to your settings controller